# Undefined Constant and Assigning the return value of new by reference Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database class in which I am calling a config file using required_once. In that I have declared some constants using define(). I am getting errors of Undefined constant and also assigning the return value of new by reference. Here is the config file code:

```
<?php

// Database Constants
defined("DB_SERVER") ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined("DB_USER")   ? null : define("DB_USER", "root");
defined("DB_PASS")   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "");
defined("DB_NAME")   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "shareysmile");

?>
```

and here is my database class code (Both are in same directory so that's not the problem):

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {

    private $connection;
    public $last_query;
    private $magic_quotes_active;
    private $real_escape_string_exists;

  function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
        $this->magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
        $this->real_escape_string_exists = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" );
  }

    public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        } else {
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
            if (!$db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }

    public function close_connection() {
        if(isset($this->connection)) {
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->last_query = $sql;
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    public function escape_value( $value ) {
        if( $this->real_escape_string_exists ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
            // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
            if( $this->magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
        } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
            // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
            if( !$this->magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
            // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
        }
        return $value;
    }

    // "database-neutral" methods
  public function fetch_array($result_set) {
    return mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
  }

  public function num_rows($result_set) {
   return mysql_num_rows($result_set);
  }

  public function insert_id() {
    // get the last id inserted over the current db connection
    return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
  }

  public function affected_rows() {
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->connection);
  }

    private function confirm_query($result) {
        if (!$result) {
        $output = "Database query failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
        //$output .= "Last SQL query: " . $this->last_query;
        die( $output );
        }
    }

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();


?>
```

I can't understand the problem, can anyone help? Here are the exact errors I get:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in D:\xampp\htdocs\sharesmile\src\database.php on line 18

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in D:\xampp\htdocs\sharesmile\src\database.php on line 18

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in D:\xampp\htdocs\sharesmile\src\database.php on line 18
```

Comment: `defined("DB_SERVER") or define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");` is the cleaner.

Comment: [defined](http://php.net/defined) always returns a boolean value. It never returns NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that the `config.php` you are including includes `D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php`, not your config file. This is due to the `PEAR` directory having a higher priority than `.` in your include path. Use the absolute path (`__DIR__ . '/config.php'`) to make it work reliably, or change your include path.

Comment: Awesome catch! I didn't know this one.

Comment: The moral of the story: always read your error messages in full and investigate based on them.

Comment: Another case of not trusting relative( path)s. **:D**

Comment: Awesome Thanks mate now i understand that i must use the absolute paths..!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
require_once("config.php");
```

with

```
require_once("../includes/config.php");
```

in your `database.php` file.

I am assuming both files are in the include directory here.